# Page refresh after postback in UpdatePanel on Sharepoint 2013 publishing page

Tags: asp.net, ajax, sharepoint, updatepanel

When I try to execute a second xmlhttprequest in UpdatePanel on sharepoint 2013 in firefox before the first one is finished, I get whole page refresh.
First request status is Aborted.
Second request response is:
1|#||4|97|pageRedirect||%2f_login%2fdefault.aspx%3fReturnUrl%3d%252fsites%252ftest%252fPages%252fUpdatePanelTest.aspx|

This error can be reproduced with the attached code (clicking the button twice quickly produces the error).

This problem occurs only if I place Web Part with this control on Publishing page on Sharepoint 2013.

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="TestUpdatePanel.ascx.cs"
Inherits="Example.TestUpdatePanel" %><asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />
    <asp:CheckBoxList runat="server" ID="CheckboxList1" AutoPostBack="true">
        <asp:ListItem Text="CheckBox1" Value="valueFromCheckBox1" />
        <asp:ListItem Text="CheckBox2" Value="valueFromCheckBox2" />
        <asp:ListItem Text="CheckBox3" Value="valueFromCheckBox3" />
        <asp:ListItem Text="CheckBox4" Value="valueFromCheckBox4" />
        <asp:ListItem Text="CheckBox5" Value="valueFromCheckBox5" />
    </asp:CheckBoxList>
</ContentTemplate></asp:UpdatePanel><asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server">
<Triggers>
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="CheckboxList1" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
</Triggers>
<ContentTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
    <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" OnClick="Button2_Click" Text="Button" />
    <br />
    <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
</ContentTemplate></asp:UpdatePanel>





    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckboxList1.SelectedIndexChanged += CheckboxList1_SelectedIndexChanged;
    }

    private void CheckboxList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
        Label3.Text = CheckboxList1.SelectedValue;
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
        Label1.Text = "Button1_Click";
    }
    protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
        Label2.Text = "Button2_Click";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you intentionally want to allow the user to submit a postback request while there is already a request going on?  If this is unintentional, you may want to consider disabling user controls while a server sided method is running.  This can be accomplished with the UpdateProgress control.  The idea is that you can use this control to pop up a div that covers the entire application while a post back is occurring.  It can be used like this:

```
<asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" >
   <ProgressTemplate >
      <div id="wait" style="width:100%; height:100%; 
               position:absolute; top:0; left:0; z-index:1000;background-color: #666699; 
               filter: alpha(opacity=80); text-align:center; vertical-align:middle;">
         <div style="border:5px solid black; width:200px; height:50px; 
               background- color:White; top:50%; position:absolute;">
                Saving changes.  Please wait...                                       
         </div>                                       
      </div>                                      
   </ProgressTemplate>
</asp:UpdateProgress>
```

Answer (score 0):

By default the updatepanels won't work in SP 2013. You have to follow the below article where there is a fix:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb861877.aspx